# Drag and drop to move row in List SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I'm working with List in SwiftUI. I want to add feature of drag and drop row(items) in List. In Swift we have UITableView's Delegate and DataSource methods like below:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath;
```

What is the alternative of these method in SwiftUI?

```
struct User {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

struct UserRow: View {
    var user: User

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(user.firstName) \(user.lastName)")
    }
}

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {

        let user1 = User(firstName: "Anjali", lastName: "User1")
        let user2 = User(firstName: "XYZ", lastName: "User2")

        return List {
            UserRow(user: user1)
            UserRow(user: user2)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you watched any WWDC videos? For instance, the very first one called "Introducing SwiftUI: Building your first app"? They demonstrate what I think (hard to say, your code dump isn't working well) you want. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/204 In case this *isn't* what you are looking for, please, you need to be more specific. Thanks, and good luck!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the WWDC there is a video that explain briefly how to activate edit mode on a list and how to move items.

You can use the `onMove` modifier to handle cell reordering, and the `EditButton()` to activate the edit mode, which allows you to move cells manually.

Note that you **can't** use the `onMove` method on a static list. This modifier is available in the `DynamicViewContent` protocol, which is implemented by `ForEach`, but not by `List`.

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    let users = [
        User(firstName: "Anjali", lastName: "User1"),
        User(firstName: "XYZ", lastName: "User2")
    ]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(users.identified(by: \.firstName)) { user in
                    UserRow(user: user)
                }.onMove(perform: move)
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Users"))
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
        }
    }

    func move(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
        users.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
    }
}
```

To make it always draggable without `EditButton` just add this modifier to your List:

```
.environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active))
```

Comment: Thanks, It works for me. Is it possible to move items without activating edit mode?

Comment: @rraphael Do you mind adding the reference to the WWDC video.

Comment: @AnjaliKevadiya I've added solution to move items without edit button

Comment: @DimaRostopira where it is?

Comment: @AnjaliKevadiya last line in answer: `.environment(\.editMode, Binding.constant(EditMode.active))`